# Show that if dynamical system $T$ is weakly mixing, then $T^n$ is weakly mixing.

Tags: dynamical-systems, mixing

Show that if dynamical system $(X,T)$ is weakly-mixing, then $(X, T^n)$ is weakly mixing.

I am using this definition of weakly mixing: we say that system is weakly mixing if system $(X^2, T \times T$) is transitive.

So now I know that for every nonempty, open sets $U_1, V_1, U_2, V_2 ⊂ X $ there exists $m ∈ N$ such that $T^m(U_1\times U_2)∩(V_1 \times V_2) \ne ∅$.

I need to show that $(X^2, T^n \times T^n)$ is transitive, so that for every nonempty, open sets $U_1, V_1, U_2, V_2 ⊂ X $ there exists $k ∈ N$ such that $T^{nk}(U_1\times U_2)∩(V_1 \times V_2) \ne ∅$.

I lack experience in dynamical systems, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It appears to me that if you replace $U_1,V_1,U_2,V_2$ by their inverse images under $T^{-n}$ in the hypothesis you will get the result. If this is not true then I have mis-understood your notations :-)